# How can I load a class without running its initializer?

Tags: java, classloader

I would like to load a class that throws an exception in its class initializer. Catching the `ExceptionInInitializerError` error doesn't work because I get a "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class" error when I try to use it later.

Is there any way to force Java to load a class even if its initializer throws an error?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @HotLicks: The class is part of a game and can only be initialized properly after the game is started. I am making a tool that I want to work without having to start up the game.

Comment: Well, the simple solution is use a noop for an initializer, and do your initialization later, on first "real" use.

Comment: It would be usefull if you only want to check if a class has an specific annotation so you could load it without running the static initialization.